# Checking that CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() was invoked with Moq

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, moq, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

I have a conditional statement which should looks as follows:

```
//...
if(_view.VerifyData != true)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    _view.PermanentCancellation.Cancel();
}
```

where PermanentCancellation is of type CancellationTokenSource.

Im wondering how i should set this up in my mock of _view. All attempts thus far have failed :( and i cant find an example on google.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [CancellationTokenSource.Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955.aspx) is not virtual you cannot mock it with moq.

You have two options:

Create a wrapper interface:

```
public interface ICancellationTokenSource
{
    void Cancel();
}
```

and an implementation which delegates to the wrapped CancellationTokenSource

```
public class CancellationTokenSourceWrapper : ICancellationTokenSource
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource source;

    public CancellationTokenSourceWrapper(CancellationTokenSource source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void Cancel() 
    {
        source.Cancel();
    }

}
```

And use the `ICancellationTokenSource` as `PermanentCancellation` then you can create an `Mock<ICancellationTokenSource>` in your tests:

```
// arrange

var mockCancellationTokenSource = new Mock<ICancellationTokenSource>();
viewMock.SetupGet(m => m.PermanentCancellation)
        .Returns(mockCancellationTokenSource.Object)

// act

// do something

// assert

mockCancellationTokenSource.Verify(m => m.Cancel());
```

And use the `CancellationTokenSourceWrapper` in your production code.

Or use a mocking framework which supports mocking non virtual members like:

- [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx)
- [Typemock isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) (commercial)
- [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx) (commercial)

Comment: Hi Nemesv, thanks for replying. Im a little confused though. The ICancellationTokenSource only contains void Cancel(); Where is PermanentCancellation/the return type? (Im sorry if this is a stupid question).

Comment: You've just shown the Cancel method in your sample. If you use more methods from `CancellationTokenSource` you need to add all of them to `ICancellationTokenSource`. And you need to change the type of the `PermanentCancellation` property to `ICancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: If im not mistaken, CancellationTokenSourceWrapper should be a class not an interface. I have then just injected that class into the presenter and also declared a property for the cancellationtokensource in ICancellationTokenSource, thus allowing me to change what its assigned to. I then just setup the Cancel() in my mock of ICancellationTokenSource and verify its called. If you would be willing to change the interface to class (assuming i havent made a mistake) i will accept this as the answer. thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Yes `CancellationTokenSourceWrapper` should be a class, sorry for the confusion. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. Np, i managed to figure out how to get it working from the rest of ur answer. thanks again for your time, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

I went a step further and made a `factory` to create a `CancellationTokenManager` class that implements the interface.  This was because my method has to take `CancellationToken` and I wanted granular control over `.IsCancellationRequested()`:

My `CancellationTokenManagerFactory`:

```
public interface ICancellationTokenManagerFactory
{
  ICancellationTokenManager CreateManager(CancellationToken token);
}

public class CancellationTokenManagerFactory : ICancellationTokenManagerFactory
{
  public ICancellationTokenManager CreateManager(CancellationToken token)
  {
    return new CancellationTokenManager(token);
  }
}
```

and the manager:

```
public interface ICancellationTokenManager
{
  bool IsCancellationRequested { get; }

  CancellationToken CancellationToken { get; }
}

public class CancellationTokenManager : ICancellationTokenManager
{
  private readonly CancellationToken _token;

  public CancellationTokenManager(CancellationToken token)
  {
    _token = token;
  }

  public bool IsCancellationRequested
  {
    get
    {
      return _token.IsCancellationRequested;
    }
  }

  public CancellationToken CancellationToken => _token;
}
```

Then in a class utilizing:

```
public class MyService
{
  private readonly ICancellationTokenManagerFactory _factory = factory;
  public MyService(ICancellationTokenManagerFactory factory)
  {
    _factory = factory;
  }

  public void StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
  {
    manager = _factory.CreateManager(token);

    //check if cancelled
    if (!manager.IsCancellationRequested())
    }
      // do some work
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I check cancellation is requested more than once i can mock with different responses each time.  Additionally, any interfaces like `IHostService` can still be utilized because `CancellationToken` is passed in although it doesn't necessarily matter what is in that token.

Comment: So what lifetime did you use for the factory?