# Mock CancellationTokenSource in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method which cancels the `CancellationTokenSource` after a specific amount of time

```
public void Reset( CancellationTokenSource source, int ms) 
{
   source.cancelAfter(ms);
}
```

I have the following code which calls reset

```
public void method1(source, ms) 
{
   Reset(source, 10);
   Reset(source, 10);
   Reset(source, 10);
   Reset(source, 20);
   Reset(source, 20);
}
```

I am writing some unit tests for my code and need to check that `cancelAfter` method is called 5 times ( 3 times with 10 and 2 times with 20)

Unfortunately, I am unable to create a Moq class for `CancellationTokenSource` and I also cannot create a new interface for it.

Comment: Include the actual subject under test and the actual test so far. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the actual problem.

Comment: There is not much of a solution that can be suggested given the stated restrictions and the incomplete example provided..

Comment: @Nikosi Thanks for the comment - I will try to produce an example for it. I believe the question is fairly self explanatory.

Comment: I can understand why you would believe that. You can see the actual code involved. We can't.Not with what has been currently provided.

Comment: If we have a broader view of the subject code, who knows, maybe we can see a possible workaround, since this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Check the second option provided in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264552/5233410